# Validating css color names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've written a jQuery plugin that accepts css colors for some of its parameters.

I want to validate them. If it was just a hex or rgb value I could do that with a regular expression, but how do I validate all 147 valid color names without bloating the plugin?

I was wondering if there is some way of attempting to apply a style (maybe with jquery) and then catching an error from the browser if it is not valid?

Edit: powtac and Pantelis came up with a solution, but they both missed edge cases, so I am including a full solution here:

```
var validateCssColour = function(colour){
    var rgb = $('<div style="color:#28e32a">');     // Use a non standard dummy colour to ease checking for edge cases
    var valid_rgb = "rgb(40, 227, 42)";
    rgb.css("color", colour);
    if(rgb.css('color') == valid_rgb && colour != ':#28e32a' && colour.replace(/ /g,"") != valid_rgb.replace(/ /g,""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
};
```

Comment: very interesting question.  i like it.

Comment: I thought there were only 17 (counting orange)?

Comment: @kennebec : see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check if css value is supported by the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191797/4642212), as the new `CSS.supports` API is available for this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All of the solutions posted on this page are incorrect when the string in question is the same colour as the test colour. Granted, you could use a very unlikely choice of colour, but I would prefer to go for 100% success rate.

OP has a single typo in his code (see condition with colon), and does not test for "#28e32a", so that colour will fail, and the regex will collapse whitespace within the colour, so "#28e 32a" would (incorrectly) pass.

In normal JavaScript, this should have 100% success:

```
function validTextColour(stringToTest) {
    //Alter the following conditions according to your need.
    if (stringToTest === "") { return false; }
    if (stringToTest === "inherit") { return false; }
    if (stringToTest === "transparent") { return false; }

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    image.style.color = stringToTest;
    if (image.style.color !== "rgb(0, 0, 0)") { return true; }
    image.style.color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    image.style.color = stringToTest;
    return image.style.color !== "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WK_of_Angmar/xgA5C/

Comment: I like your line of thinking, but this fails for "rgb(0,0,0)"

Comment: Why do you have the last two lines instead of just `return false`?

Comment: That's because I missed out a line (see edit). The last two lines are essentially for the case "rgb(0,0,0)" with or without spaces. In other words, we first assume that the colour the user has given is NOT white and so if the colour of the image has changed, it is a valid input. The last two lines assumes that it might be a valid input but it is white so the colour of the image should change from black to something else.

Comment: It should now work for "rgb(0,0,0)" - with and without spaces in between.

Comment: This will also return true for `rgb(0, 0, 0` - even though the `)` is missing

Comment: still not working when entering `#000` or `black`, your function has racial bugs

Answer (score 32):

I know this question is fairly old but I came up with a **pure javascript solution** for checking colors which seems to work in every browser and wanted to share it

**This function uses the browser to convert any input string into a CSS color string (if possible)**

```
function getColorCSS(c) {
    const ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.style.color = c;
    return ele.style.color.replace(/\s+/,'').toLowerCase();
}
```

---

*UPDATE*: The beauty of using the browser itself to render color strings is that it continues to work with newer formats like [8 digit hex](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa) (where the last 2 digits represent alpha)...

[image: eight digit hex example]

---

Let's take a look at the function output based on different inputs...

## INVALID INPUTS

Basically anytime the browser can't figure out how to render the input string as a color an `empty string` is returned which makes this tiny function perfect for detecting invalid color strings!

- ### `redd`, `#f0gf0g`, `#1234`, `f00`, `rgb(1,2)`, `rgb(1,2,3.0)`, `rgb(1,2,3,4)`, `rgba(100,150,200)`

  - . . . **chrome**
  - . . . **firefox**
  - . . . **internet explorer**

## VALID INPUTS

- ### `tomato`

  - `tomato` . . . **chrome**
  - `tomato` . . . **firefox**
  - `tomato` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `#f00`, `#ff0000`, `rgb(255,0,0)`

  - `rgb(255,0,0)` . . . **chrome**
  - `rgb(255,0,0)` . . . **firefox**
  - `rgb(255,0,0)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `rgba(255,0,0,1.0)`, `rgba(255,0,0,100)`

  - `rgb(255,0,0)` . . . **chrome** converts `rgba` to `rgb` anytime alpha is `1.0` or greater since it's fully opaque anyway (probably for performance)
  - `rgb(255,0,0)` . . . **firefox** does the same thing as chrome
  - `rgba(255,0,0,1)` . . . **internet explorer** converts the alpha param from `1.0` or greater to `1`

- ### `rgba(0,255,0,0.5)`

  - `rgba(0,255,0,0.498039)` . . . **chrome** returns something different than the other browsers (possibly trading accuracy for performance)
  - `rgba(0,255,0,0.5)` . . . **firefox**
  - `rgba(0,255,0,0.5)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `rgba(0,0,255,0.0)`, `rgba(0,0,255,-100)`

  - `rgba(0,0,255,0)` . . . **chrome** converts the alpha param from `0.0` or lower to `0`
  - `rgba(0,0,255,0)` . . . **firefox** does the same
  - `rgba(0,0,255,0)` . . . **internet explorer** does the same

- ### `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, `rgba(0,0,0,-100)`

  - `rgba(0,0,0,0)` . . . **chrome**
  - `transparent` . . . **firefox** converts only this one `rgba` instance with all parameters set to `0` to the word `transparent` (strange)
  - `rgba(0,0,0,0)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `hsl(180,50%,50%)`

  - `rgb(63,191,191)` . . . **chrome**
  - ff  `rgb(63,191,191)` . . . **firefox**
  - ie  `hsl(180,50%,50%)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `hsl(x,x,0%)`

  - `rgb(0,0,0)` . . . **chrome**
  - `rgb(0,0,0)` . . . **firefox**
  - `hsl(0,0%,0%)` . . . **internet explorer** converts any hsl representation of `black` to this

- ### `hsl(x,x,100%)`

  - `rgb(255,255,255)` . . . **chrome**
  - `rgb(255,255,255)` . . . **firefox**
  - `hsl(0,0%,100%)` . . . **internet explorer** converts any hsl representation of `white` to this

- ### `hsla(180,50%,50%,1.0)`, `hsla(180,50%,50%,100)`

  - `rgba(63,191,191,1)` . . . **chrome**
  - `rgba(63,191,191,1)` . . . **firefox**
  - `hsla(180,50%,50%,1)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `hsla(180,50%,50%,0.5)`

  - `rgba(63,191,191,0.498039)` . . . **chrome**
  - `rgba(63,191,191,0.5)` . . . **firefox**
  - `hsla(180,50%,50%,0.5)` . . . **internet explorer**

- ### `hsla(0,0%,0%,0.0)`, `hsla(0,0%,0%,-100)`

  - `rgba(0,0,0,0)` . . . **chrome**
  - `transparent` . . . **firefox** is consistent but this conversion still seems strange
  - `hsla(180,50%,50%,0)` . . . **internet explorer**

---

> Wow, I can hardly believe I just spent 2 hours testing that function in different browsers!

> I guess I may as well demo using the function while I'm at it...

```js
function getColorCSS(c) {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.style.color = c;
    return ele.style.color.split(/\s+/).join('').toLowerCase();
}

function isColorValid(c) {
    var s = getColorCSS(c);
    return (s) ? true : false;
}

function isColorTransparent(c) {
    var s = getColorCSS(c);
    return (
        s === "transparent" || 
        s.substring(0,4) === "rgba" && +s.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1') <= 0 ||
        s.substring(0,4) === "hsla" && +s.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1') <= 0
    );
}

function isColorWhite(c) {
    var s = getColorCSS(c);
    return [
        "white",
        "rgb(255,255,255)",
        "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        "hsl(0,0%,100%)",
        "hsla(0,0%,100%,1)"
    ].indexOf(s) > -1;
}

function isColorBlack(c) {
    var s = getColorCSS(c);
    return [
        "black",
        "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        "hsl(0,0%,0%)",
        "hsla(0,0%,0%,1)"
    ].indexOf(s) > -1;
}

function checkColorString() {
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  
  if (c === "") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';
  }
  else if (isColorValid(c)) {
    if (isColorTransparent(c)) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span style="color:#dadada;">TRANSPARENT</span>';
    }
    else if (isColorWhite(c)) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = getColorCSS(c);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span style="color:black;">WHITE</span>';
    }
    else if (isColorBlack(c)) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = getColorCSS(c);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span style="color:white;">BLACK</span>';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = getColorCSS(c);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getColorCSS(c);
    }
  }
  else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:42px;color:#dadada;">&#9785</span>';
  }
}

var eventList = ["change", "keyup", "paste", "input", "propertychange"];
for(event of eventList) {
    document.getElementById("c").addEventListener(event, function() {
      checkColorString();
    });
}
```

```css
#c {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: courier;
}

#result {
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 6px;
}
```

```html
<input id="c" placeholder="Enter any valid CSS color..."></input>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: one thing I don't understand...
why do `str.split(/\s+/).join("")` instead of simply `str.replace(/\s+/g, "")`

Comment: and somehow, if anyone really hates to create element every time, you can try `document.head.style.color` (but not if your page does not have head unfortunately), and such: `return [document.head.style.color = "I am color", document.head.style.color][1]` (I do believe replacing the space is not necessary.

Comment: Good call — I updated the function to do a replace instead of split/join.

Comment: @Valen — Maybe replacing spaces is overkill but since I can’t control what every browser returns I think it’s better to remove white space to ensure invalid conversions return something falsey

Answer (score 13):

You could simply set the color to a dummy element and then check if the element's value is something other than white.

```
colorToTest = 'lime'; // 'lightgray' does not work for IE

$('#dummy').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
$('#dummy').css('backgroundColor', colorToTest);
if ($('#dummy').css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || colorToTest == 'white') {
    alert(colorToTest+' is valid');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to make one amendment; use a non standard color for the check that can only be represented with a six digit hex or an rgb. Your code would fail for colorToTest = '#fff' and '#ffffff'. Using a non standard color simplifies it.

Comment: Also need to include to remove whitespace when checking rgb values.

Comment: A tweak to this is to set both the color and backgroundColor fields to the new colour. If afterwards the two CSS elements are the same, then this is a valid colour.

Answer (score 7):

```js
function test(myColor) {
  var valid = $('#test').css('color');

  $('#test').css('color', myColor);

  if (valid == $('#test').css('color')) alert("INVALID COLOR");
  else {
    alert("VALID");
    $('#test').css('color', valid);
  }
}


test("TATATA");
test("white");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">asdasdasdasd</div>
```

It is hastily written but it works.

Comment: Fails for `black`... But you could check: `if (color == "black") OK else validation_code`

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct. It fails because it checks for 
valid== $('#test').css('color')  and  black is its default value. It can be fixed with the way you mention. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Your idea is the same as powtacs. Only he got there 30 or so seconds before you so I awarded him the credit. It's a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm arriving a little bit late but now I'm using [validate-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-color) library on npm

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the script from this [page](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/) that does exactly what you want: you pass a string to it and tries to figure out the color. Ok, it's not exactly what you wanted to do but it should work.

I think that in any case at some point you should do a name lookup (i don't think there is some magic way to determine the hex value from the string "light blue") so just snatch the work some one else has done (the script is by Stoyan Stefanov which is very good at javascript, i've read some good books from him, and if he does a lookup, well, i don't think there is another solution)

Answer (score 0):

crazy thought

```
function isValidCssColor(c){
    // put !! to normalize to boolean
    return [
            document.head.style.color = c,
            document.head.style.color,
            document.head.style.color = null
    ][1]; // split it in 3 lines is fine, see snippet
}
```

I believe it works (only not when your pages doesn't not have a `head` element, somehow)

```js
function isValidCssColor(c){
  document.head.style.color = c;
  let result = document.head.style.color;
  document.head.style.color = null;
  return result;
}

console.log(isValidCssColor("asdf"));       // <empty string>
console.log(isValidCssColor("black"));      // black
console.log(isValidCssColor("#abcdee"));    // rgb(171, 205, 238) // this is browser dependent I guess
console.log(isValidCssColor("asssdf"));     // <empty string>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just returns the value of the last successful call. I like the idea of setting the color of the head element though!

Comment: @SteveBennett ez fix

Answer (score 0):

#### Short JavaScript version

Inspired by Valen's answer:

```
v=c=>((s=document.head.style).color=c,q=s.color,s.color='',!!q);
// v('red') => true
// v('reeeed') => false
```

More readably:

```js
const validColor = c => {
  document.head.style.color = c;
  const q = document.head.style.color;
  document.head.style.color = '';
  return !!q
};
```