# CSS - How to sort inline-block in vertical top to bottom instead of left to right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, css-multicolumn-layout

I've got a set of divs displayed in 5 columns using `display: inline-block`.

I want them to stack like this:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Instead of:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

What I have so far:

```css
#parent {
  width: 1200px; 
}

.withchild {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">1</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">2 </a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">3</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">4</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">5</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">6</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">7</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">8</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">9</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">10</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">11</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">12</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">13</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">14</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">15</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">16</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">17</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">18</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">19</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">20</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">21</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">22</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">23</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">24</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">25</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">26</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">27</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">28</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">29</a > </div>
  <div class="withchild"> <a href="#">30</a > </div>
</div>
```

How can I make them stack top to bottom instead of left to right?

Comment: Try with CSS column-count Property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp.

Comment: Tried with that but it seems not supported by all browsers, didn't work well on safari.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Basically, you use `flex-direction: column` to stack the elements vertically and `flex-wrap: wrap` + `height: 100vh` to make them wrap when there's no more vertical space available.

You can then use [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) and [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to change the way they are aligned on both axis.

If you want to always have the same number of columns, in this case 5, but do not want to use [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count), you need to set `width: 20%` on the items and then, assuming they all have the same `height`, set the `height` of the parent using JavaScript to match that:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const items = parent.children;
const rows = Math.ceil(items.length / 5);

parent.style.height = `${ items[0].offsetHeight * rows }px`;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.withchild {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Always keep the text in 1 line: */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.withchild:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="withchild">1</div>
  <div class="withchild">2</div>
  <div class="withchild">3</div>
  <div class="withchild">4</div>
  <div class="withchild">5</div>
  <div class="withchild">6</div>
  <div class="withchild">7</div>
  <div class="withchild">8</div>
  <div class="withchild">9</div>
  <div class="withchild">10</div>
  <div class="withchild">11</div>
  <div class="withchild">12</div>
  <div class="withchild">13</div>
  <div class="withchild">14</div>
  <div class="withchild">15</div>
  <div class="withchild">16</div>
  <div class="withchild">17</div>
  <div class="withchild">18</div>
  <div class="withchild">19</div>
  <div class="withchild">20</div>
  <div class="withchild">21</div>
  <div class="withchild">22</div>
  <div class="withchild">23</div>
  <div class="withchild">24</div>
  <div class="withchild">25</div>
  <div class="withchild">26</div>
  <div class="withchild">27</div>
  <div class="withchild">28</div>
  <div class="withchild">29</div>
  <div class="withchild">30</div>
  <div class="withchild">31</div>
  <div class="withchild">32</div>
</div>
```

Here's the alternative without JavaScript using [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count), which you can see on MDN and on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) that I think has pretty good support in modern browsers (using vendor prefixes):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#parent {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.withchild {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Always keep the text in 1 line: */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 23px;
}

.withchild:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="withchild">1</div>
  <div class="withchild">2</div>
  <div class="withchild">3</div>
  <div class="withchild">4</div>
  <div class="withchild">5</div>
  <div class="withchild">6</div>
  <div class="withchild">7</div>
  <div class="withchild">8</div>
  <div class="withchild">9</div>
  <div class="withchild">10</div>
  <div class="withchild">11</div>
  <div class="withchild">12</div>
  <div class="withchild">13</div>
  <div class="withchild">14</div>
  <div class="withchild">15</div>
  <div class="withchild">16</div>
  <div class="withchild">17</div>
  <div class="withchild">18</div>
  <div class="withchild">19</div>
  <div class="withchild">20</div>
  <div class="withchild">21</div>
  <div class="withchild">22</div>
  <div class="withchild">23</div>
  <div class="withchild">24</div>
  <div class="withchild">25</div>
  <div class="withchild">26</div>
  <div class="withchild">27</div>
  <div class="withchild">28</div>
  <div class="withchild">29</div>
  <div class="withchild">30</div>
  <div class="withchild">31</div>
  <div class="withchild">32</div>
</div>
```

Anyway, you can always use a mix of both solutions if you prefer to use `column-count` in browsers that support it and use Flexbox and a bit of JavaScript as a fallback.

Comment: That wouldn't work, I need 5 columns across, and as this is for a dynamic navigation menu, the items will vary, I can't give a defined height: 100vh;

Comment: @Joe Take a look at the updated answer. To do that with Flexbox you need to use JavaScript to set the `height` of the parent. Alternatively, `column-count` has pretty good support in modern browsers using vendor prefixes, but it depends on which browsers and versions you need to support.

Comment: This seems to be the best option so far... how would I do the Flexbox and JavaScript fallback?

Comment: You need separated classes for each version and apply one or the other depending on whether `column-count` is supported. Here's how to check if a CSS property is supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191797/how-to-check-if-css-value-is-supported-by-the-browser