# How to check if -webkit-text-stroke is supported in browser

Tags: css, sass, webkit, textcolor

I am having a problem to check if the current browser supports the `-webkit-text-stroke`. I tried using `@media all and (-webkit-text-stroke)` and `@if -webkit-text-stroke {}`, but with no success.

I have the following code:

```
color: transparent;
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #ffffff;
font-size: 9rem;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
top: 35%;
left: 5%;
font-family: $font__kalam;
width: fit-content;
```

I'd like to know how to check if the property `-webkit-text-stroke` is supported by the browser. If it's not supported I'd like to use: `color: $white;` instead of the `-webkit-text-stroke` and the `color: transparent`. Is there any way in SCSS **only** to make this happen?

Thank you in advance.

~ Sander

Comment: Can you use the method described in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191797/how-to-check-if-css-value-is-supported-by-the-browser

Comment: I'll try, thank you.

Comment: This wasn't the solution I was looking for. I'm looking for a CSS / SCSS only method. And I'd like to know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@supports` to test this.

```
@supports (-webkit-text-stroke: green) {
  div {
    -webkit-text-stroke:green;
  }
}
```

> The @supports CSS at-rule lets you specify declarations that depend on a browser's support for one or more specific CSS features. This is called a feature query. The rule may be placed at the top level of your code or nested inside any other conditional group at-rule.
>
> [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

Answer (score -1):

Use **https://caniuse.com/**

> **For -webkit-text-stroke visit: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_-webkit-text-stroke**

[image: caniuse.com]

Comment: I know which browsers supports the `-webkit-text-stroke` method. But I want to know based on the user's browser. For example, if I use a browser that does not support the property, I need to have a backup plan to make sure the text does not stay transparent.

Comment: `color: $white;` will be supported by almost all. If you will add such functionality, it will just increase your work, file size and may decrease your website speed

Comment: I was talking about the `-webkit-text-stroke` property. `color: $white` will be converted to `#ffffff`in my case. And `color` is a pretty general property so must be supported by all browsers. But I was wondering if the `-webkit-text-stroke` is supported as well and if it isn't, I need to set the color to `$white` instead of `transparent`.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I get something.