# Check if string is a valid CSS color expression?

Tags: javascript, css, validation, input

If I have a string that is a CSS code to be used as a color, **Is it possible to check the value validity?**

### What i want is:

A function or a regex to validate if inputted code is a valid CSS code where it returns true when the value is a CSS function as `linear-gradient`, color names as `red`, hex, rgb, hsl colors or `initial, inherit, currentColor, transparent` values, and returns false otherwise.

Like:

```
check('linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(85, 85, 85, 1) 89%, rgba(153, 153, 153, 1) 100%)'); // should return true
check('#abcdzzff') // should return false
check('aquamarin') // should also return false (missing e)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are can access DOM (running on a browser), the best answer to your question seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386090/validating-css-color-names

Comment: @StefanWang it works great for rgb hsl and others but it doesn't work for CSS function, do you happen to know another code for CSS functions? I'm fine with 2 functions.

Comment: @StefanWang so i kept messing around with that code and it works fine now if instead of writing `image.style.color` i write `image.style.background`.
It wouldn't work for `rgb(0, 0, 0)` but you can easily write an if case for it. SO if you care, please write an answer so i can mark it, thanks.

Comment: You can use image.style

Comment: You mean [`CSS.supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check if css value is supported by the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191797/4642212).

Answer (score -2):

Since @StefanWang doesn't want to post his answer, I shall post it myself.

I credit this to him, thank you stefan.

```js
let validate = c => {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.style = 'background: rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    img.style = 'background: ' + c;
    if (img.style.background != 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' && img.style.background != '') return true;
    img.style = 'background: rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    img.style = 'background: ' + c;
    return (img.style.background != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' && img.style.background != '');
}

console.log(validate('transparent')); // true
console.log(validate('hsl(30, 60%, 90%)')); // true
console.log(validate('linear-gradient(140deg, #000 0%, #666 90%, #ccc 100%)')); // true
console.log(validate('red')); // true
console.log(validate('#000')); // true
console.log(validate('#zzz')); // false
```